# What does Array#reverse method in Ruby do?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, ruby-2.1

In Ruby, when I call `reverse` method on an array, it doesn't reverse sort the array completely.

```
array = [5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 1, 2]

array.reverse # => [2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

I'm unable to understand what operation it's performing on the array.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-reverse

Comment: @ChrisHeald I was there in first place, but that gave me a very short description of the method, too short to grasp it. Therefore, I asked it here!

Comment: `reverse` does no sorting, it just reverses the order of the elements in the list.

Comment: @JesseMu Got it. It is so easy thing, and I wasn't understanding it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> array
 => [5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 1, 2] 
> array.sort.reverse  # it will sort the array by value in descending order
 => [9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1]
```

**Note:**

- **[sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-sort)** : Returns a new array created by sorting self.
- **[reverse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-reverse)** : Returns a new array containing self‘s elements in reverse order.

See how it works:

```
> array.reverse   # it will reverse the array by indexing
 => [2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5] 
> array.sort  # it will sort the array by value in ascending order
 => [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Array#reverse reverses the order of an array, but does not sort the array in reverse order.

```
array = [1,5,7,3]
array.reverse
=> [3,7,5,1]
```

If you want to sort an array in reverse order, you could try this

```
array.sort_by{|a|array.max - a}
```